# Laravel Eloquent where and or between in one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

Hello what is the Laravel eloquent code for this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dtrs
 inner join emp_informations
    on dtrs.enrollnum = emp_informations.enrollnum
 where (emp_informations.EmpID = '07081408')
   and (date_in between '2015-03-05' and '2015-03-20' and
       date_out between '2015-03-05' and '2015-03-20')
 ORDER BY dtrs . date_in DESC
```

Here's my code in eloquent, and it doesn't show the same result with the original query.

```
  $dtrs=Dtr::Join('emp_informations','dtrs.enrollnum','=','emp_informations.enrolnum')
          ->where('emp_informations.first_name','like',"%$id%")
          ->orWhere('emp_informations.last_name','like',"%$id%")
          ->whereBetween('dtrs.date_in', array('2015-03-05' , '2015-03-20'))
          ->orderBy('dtrs.date_in','Desc')->paginate(15);

 return view('timetrack' , compact('dtrs'));
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Oh come on, at least try something yourself first. We can help you when you get stuck but we're not a code-writing service.

Comment: $dtrs = Dtr::Join('emp_informations','dtrs.enrollnum','=','emp_informations.enrollnum')->where('emp_informations.first_name','like',"%$id%")->orWhere('emp_informations.last_name','like',"%$id%")->whereBetween('dtrs.date_in', array('2015-03-05' , '2015-03-20'))->orderBy('dtrs.date_in','Desc')->paginate(15);
  return view('timetrack' , compact('dtrs'));

Comment: thats  my code and it doesnt show the same result with the original query

Comment: Yes, much better. Please put it in your question as code, and I'll remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed somethings in your query, please try this :

```
  $dtrs=Dtr::Join('emp_informations','dtrs.enrollnum','=','emp_informations.enrolnum')
          ->where('emp_informations.EmpID','=','07081408')
          ->whereBetween('dtrs.date_in', array('2015-03-05' , '2015-03-20'))
          ->whereBetween('dtrs.date_out', array('2015-03-05' , '2015-03-20'))
          ->orderBy('dtrs.date_in','Desc')->paginate(15);
```

if you have variables, you can make like this:

```
->whereBetween('dtrs.date_in', array($fromdate , $todate))
```

Comment: ok it works.. but when i change the values with variables it doesnt show anything..

Comment: which values do you want to change? 

for example, you can make like this :                                              

->whereBetween('dtrs.date_in', array($fromdate , $todate))

Comment: i edited my answer and i have written example for variables too

Comment: thanks it works now.. i put wherebetween first before the first where

Comment: #kevinb I'm glad I was able to help